# ReSharper (or something like it) for Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, resharper

I've seen ReSharper recommended a lot  Unfortunately, it doesn't support C++ in Visual Studio.  Is there anything out there you can recommend?  I already use Visual Assist, and it does its job very well, but it's quite limited in comparison with ReSharper.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882280/is-there-a-resharper-like-tool-for-c-projects

Comment: FYI - ReSharper will support C++ post version 8.  http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/06/26/resharper-to-support-c/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refactor Pro is [available](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/) for Visual C++, this will give you some functionality. Also check out CodeRush, I think it also supports C++.

Answer (score 17):

IMHO - [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) is best but expensive code completion/refactoring tool for C++.
VAX has not so much features as ReSharper for C#, but it makes your C++ programming easier and faster... Just looked on CodeRush - it su%% as most of DevExpress libs & tools.

Comment: I don't really think that DevExpress sucks. It has great tools and frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

I tried both Refactor Pro and Visual Assist/X. Neither of them thrilled me in the same way that ReSharper does. I guess that mostly, this is because C++ is such a hard language to write automatic refactorings for.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to code in Eclipse or NetBeans, but such IDEs are not Visual Studio.

Comment: +1 Even though this does not answer the question, if the OP is not limited to the IDE then i think the suggestion to use Eclipse is legitimate. My job entails programming in C# with Visual studio (we use resharper), and when i played around with android programming in eclipse A LOT of the resharper functionality was built-in to the eclipse IDE.

Comment: @StevenMagana-Zook where is this functionality. I'm using eclipse juno with cdt and the refactoring and code completion possibilites are so bad, that i'm seriously considering going back to vim. can you recommend eclipse plugins for better refactoring etc?