# ReSharper for c/c++

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++

On my .NEt projects I'm used to the tool called ReSharper but my current project is c/c++ and I so miss my loved ReSharper any one know of a tool with at least kinda the same capabilities for c/c++ (Especially refactoring and dead code analysis)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882280/is-there-a-resharper-like-tool-for-c-projects and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196828/resharper-or-something-like-it-for-visual-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some refactoring support and intellisense is ensured by Visual Assist. Pretty good actually.

However, don't expect to have the same support for refactoring as in case of ReSharper with C# or VB.NET. From this point of view, C++ is a nightmare and I don't know a tool that can do it correctly in all situations.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Assist from WholeTomato actually Software predates Resharper and is very good

Answer (score 0):

CodeRush/Refactor http://devexpress.com/coderush will work with C++, as well as VB, C#, HTML, Javascript.