# ReSharper/StyleCop-like Visual Studio addon for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, resharper, add-on

Is there any ReSharper/StyleCop-like Visual Studio addon for C/C++?

I'm using ReSharper and StyleCop addons every day. Just recently started a new project which involves C/C++ programming. I miss some features from these addons like code formatting, hints/tips to use cleaner and better code, documentation/uniform code requirements, optimizing includes and so on....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882280/is-there-a-resharper-like-tool-for-c-projects and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196828/resharper-or-something-like-it-for-visual-c and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068718/resharper-for-c-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) is pretty much the de-facto for C++ programming in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

[Refactor! for C++](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/) is a free option; I haven't used it much myself, though, so I can't vouch for quality.

Comment: always test your links in user-APIs ;)