# Is there a ReSharper-like tool for C++ projects?

Tags: c++, refactoring

I'm searching tool like ReSharper for  C++.  I want to  have a more flexible refactoring tool than Visual Assist. It is really really good but if there exists a tool like ReSharper for C++, I want to know the tool's name.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196828/resharper-or-something-like-it-for-visual-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this question a while back someone suggested "Refactor Pro", but this is 2008 there may be more modern tools that are better suited to what you are after.

[ReSharper (or something like it) for Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196828/resharper-or-something-like-it-for-visual-c)

Comment: Thanks man  can it  works on VS 2005?

Comment: Yes, "Refactor! Pro" works in VS 2005, VS 2008 and VS 2010.

Answer (score 5):

We use [WholeTomate's Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) and are quite happy. The refactoring is okay (for C++) and it "repairs" Intellisense.
Also, it adds the snippets (text macros with place holders like "function name") to VS which I use for adding formatted comments.
Autocompletion works well. 
It's not as powerful as ReSharper but I would buy it again and again because Intellisense now works. (I started with VC6 and at least since then MS didn't get Intellisense working for C++...)

Answer (score 0):

There's also a completely free version of [Refactor! for C++](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/) . The difference between Refactor! for C++ and Refactor! Pro is in number of refactorings they provide. CodeRush, which contains another coding assistance functionality, supports C++ as well. There are 30 days [trial versions](https://www.devexpress.com/ClientCenter/Downloads/#Trials).